# Foundation 4 Full Browser Width Column

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've been googling around for hours now trying to look for a way to make a column be full browser width like the top bar is. Is there a way to do this or is the only solution to just make a custom div without the div row class?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like making a div that is not a row is the best solution.

Rows will be sized by [Foundation's grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html). The size of the grid can be changed (see "Grid Variables" on [this page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html)) — but if you just want to make something fill the window, it sounds like you don't want to use the grid for this element.

Comment: Yeah this what I've been thinking. Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row collapse">
...
</div>
```